# Heroku Account Dashboard Issue

Tags: django, github, heroku, dashboard, account

Hi all i am getting this error when i log into my Heroku account.
**Item could not be modified:
Unable to fetch account**
It was working fine for the better part o the day any idea what would be the cause?

Comment: would you provide error screenshot and the code.

Comment: seems it was an issue with Heroku, now the dashboard is working normally. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it was an issue from Heroku side, dashboard is now working correctly.